# Strange behavior of String.Compare with OrdinalIgnoreCase

Tags: .net

MSDN says on StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase the following:

> TheStringComparer returned by the OrdinalIgnoreCase property treats the characters in the strings to compare as if they were converted to uppercase using the conventions of the invariant culture, and then performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of language. **This is most appropriate when comparing strings that are generated programmatically or when comparing case-insensitive resources such as paths and filenames.**

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

However, when I try to compare

```
String.Compare("‎a","A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

The returned value is `1` and not `0`.

Even stranger is this:

```
String.Compare("‎1","1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

which also returns `1` although strings are equal.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to check for equality or for sorting strings?

Comment: Checking for equality in the specific scenario I encountered this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason after an hour of digging: Turns out one of the strings contains an invisible character %e2%80%8e (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK) which is only visible when taking the string and converting it to an array.

Comment: Or when copying it into the textbox in http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure why you get this result. When I run this code via LinqPad I get 0.

If casing is not relevant you can try the other overload `String.Compare(string, string, bool)`

```
String.Compare("‎a","A", true);
String.Compare("‎1","1", true);
```

Comment: on LinqPad when I wrote the comparison it also returned 0, then I copied my comparison from this question and it returned 1. That is what led me to search for hidden chars